# How can I do this without arrays or vectors only using loops

Tags: c++

I am almost done with this project just stuck on this last part. Really need help I've reach out to teacher not getting a response. I want to display which complex enter has the highest rent total. Right now I have a double named currentRentAmount  which keeps a running total after each loop it reset. So the issue is if the first complex enter was the highest rent collected complex enter it loses that value because its reset to 0. I feel so close yet so far a way. I cant use vector/ array because we technically haven't learn it yet.

```
   // ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("rentfile.txt");
    int numComplex, numMonths;
    double rent, totalAllRent = 0; //// Accumulator for total scores
    string nameComplex;
    string highNameComplex;
    double averageRent;
    double highestComplexRent = 0;
    double currentRentAmount = 0;
    double previousRentAmount = 0;


    //set up numeric output programing
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

    cout << "How many complexes will you enter?";
    cin >> numComplex;   //number of complexes enter
    cout << "How many months of rent will you enter complex?";
    cin >> numMonths; //number of months of rent enter


    for (int complex = 1; complex <= numComplex; complex++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Complex Name ";
        cin >> nameComplex;
        outputFile << nameComplex << " ";

        for (int months = 1; months <= numMonths; months++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Rent " << months << " for ";
            cout << " Complex " << complex << ": ";
            cin >> rent;
            totalAllRent = totalAllRent + rent;
            averageRent = totalAllRent / numComplex;
            outputFile << rent << endl; //write data to output file 
            currentRentAmount = currentRentAmount + rent;
            cout << currentRentAmount << endl;


            if  (currentRentAmount > highestComplexRent)
            {
                currentRentAmount = highestComplexRent;
            }

            }   

    currentRentAmount = 0;

    }




    outputFile.close(); //close the file

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("rentfile.txt");
    cout << "Complex Monthly rent Collected per Complex " << endl;

    while (inputFile >> nameComplex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numMonths; i++)
        {
            inputFile >> rent;
            cout << nameComplex << " " << rent << endl;
            if (rent == 0)
                cout << "Warning one of the complexes submitted zero rent for one of the months " << endl;
            }
    }

            cout << "Total rent collected for the company = " << totalAllRent << endl;
            cout << " Average Monthly rent collected for the company = " << averageRent << endl;
            cout << highNameComplex << "collect the most rent = " << highestComplexRent << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider proof reading your question. What does "complex enter" mean? Also, since this is a homework assignment please tag it as so.

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the exact same question *twice* already?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable maxComplexRent to keep the track of complexRent.

```
double maxComplexRent = 0.0;
for (int complex = 1; complex <= numComplex; complex++)
{
    cout << "Enter Complex Name ";
    cin >> nameComplex;
    outputFile << nameComplex << " ";

        for (int months = 1; months <= numMonths; months++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Rent " << months << " for ";
            cout << " Complex " << complex << ": ";
            cin >> rent;
            totalAllRent = totalAllRent + rent;
            averageRent = totalAllRent / numComplex;
            outputFile << rent << endl; //write data to output file 
            currentRentAmount = currentRentAmount + rent;
            cout << currentRentAmount << endl;




            }   
    //Here
    maxComplexRent = maxComplexRent>currentRentAmount? maxComplexRent:currentRentAmount;
    currentRentAmount = 0;

    }
```

Comment: still same issue it displays the last entry as the highest when it is not

Comment: Removed that If loop. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

First a friendly note; 'Complex number' means something very specific , you are talking about apartment complex numbers. However, when most people read complex number they think x+iy (think imaginary numbers)

Second , the problem you have is one of logic. You want to find the apt complex with the highest rent, but you seem to update the highest rent value in this condition.

```
if (currentRentAmount > previousRentAmount)
{
    highestComplexRent = currentRentAmount;
}
```

Ask yourself why you are doing this , what happens in every iteration of the loop. IF `currentRentAmount > previousRentAmount` since previousRentAmount is always 0.Effectively, this means, if the value of current rent is greater than 0 highest rent is set to current rent.

What you want here is: 
1. Make sure highestRentAmount is set to 0 outside of the loops.
2. The if check should be `if(currentRentAmount > highestComplexRent)` (think through why this will work, I can tell you the answer, but just think about it for a second, its much better to arrive at it yourself)

Good luck

Comment: Hello i am trying to use logic here I post whole code so you can see now what I am trying to do

Comment: It seems you just copied what I and others were suggesting but you made a mistake in the copying , you have to set `highestComplexRent = currentRentAmount;` not what you have in your current code

Comment: i think I just figure it out

Comment: I feel like a idiot is was logic thanks if (currentRentAmount > highestComplexRent)
   {
    highestComplexRent = currentRentAmount;
   }

Comment: what you want to do every loop is compare the last known highestComplexRent to the currentRentAmount and if the currentRentAmount is higher then you just set the higestComplexRent to that value. That way, when your loops end, you will have the highest rent value in the highestComplexRent variable.

Comment: Glad you figured it out ... I hope you also understand why that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions here:

1. It does not use the correct variable:

   ```
   if (currentRentAmount > previousRentAmount)
   ```

should be changed to

```
    if (currentRentAmount > highestComplexRent)
```

2. This line should be moved out to the outer loop (although it is unused):

   ```
   averageRent = totalAllRent / numComplex;
   ```
3. Remove the unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

if statement was wrong able to fix

```
if (currentRentAmount > highestComplexRent)
        {
            highestComplexRent = currentRentAmount;
        }
```